# Function that returns iterator from a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I have a class with a `map<K,V>` variable which gets its value in the c'tor like so:

```
class Foo {
    map<K,V> m;
    Foo (map<K,V>& newM) : m(newM) {}
    map<K,V>::iterator bar () { ... }
}
```

the function `bar` iterates through the map `m`, and return some an iterator to some element. I'm calling the function like this:

```
std::map<K,V> map;
//fill map
Foo foo(map);
map<K,V>::iterator it = foo.bar();
```

my question is, at this moment, does it point to a member of `map`? or was it copied to `Foo.m` and therefor the iterator points to a different map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will point to the new map, as you copied the map into variable `m` in the ctor of the class. The statement `m(newM)` in the initialization list invokes the copy constructor of the `std::map` class and copies individual elements of the passed map into the destintation map `m`. Hence when you invoke `bar` method, it will return the iterator from this new map.

**EDIT**
Example code for storing the `std::map` as reference:

```
class Foo {
public:
    map<int,int>& m; //Note: the change here, I am storing a reference
    Foo (map<int,int>& newM) : m(newM) {}
    map<int,int>::iterator bar () { return m.begin();}
};


int main()
{
    std::map<int,int> map1;
    Foo foo(map1);
    map<int,int>::iterator it = foo.bar();

    if(it == map1.begin())
    {
        std::cout<<"Iterators are equal\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. To add: if that was intended, the Foo constructor should accept a const reference.

Comment: @Naveen is it possible to somehow make it return a pointer to the original map - using reference and not pointers?

Comment: @Amir Rachum: Yes, you can return iterator to original container if you store only a reference in your class. But note that it is *risky* as you have to make sure that your original map doesn't go out of scope until `foo` object is destroyed. Otherwise, you will end up in having an invalid reference and your code will behave unpredictably.

Comment: @Naveen can you show a quick example of the syntax? I'm a little confused with references.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator will point to the map contains in your class `Foo`. Surely that shouldn't be an issue though as you've copied the map to the class?

What I mean by that is, I assume you will do something like this:

```
map<K,V> original;
Foo foo(original);
map<K,V>::iterator it = foo.begin(), itEnd = foo.end();
for (; it != itEnd; ++it)
{
  // Do something with *it
}
```

Comment: Ownership has not been transferred -  a copy has been made.